# OpenCV imdecode returns none

Tags: python, urllib, opencv

I'm trying to read an image from url.

For this, I created the funcion below. For some url I input, it works exactly how I wish, but for others, it doesn't. In this cases the *cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)* function returns **none**.

My code:

```
import cv2     
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import numpy as np



def urlToImage(url):
    # download image,convert to a NumPy array,and read it into opencv
    req = Request(
        url,
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla5.0(Google spider)', 'Range': 'bytes=0-{}'.format(5000)})
    resp = urlopen(req)
    img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    # return the image
    return img

img = urlToImage('https://my_image.jpg')
print(img)
```

Example of url that works:

```
"https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/paisagem-ambiente-bonito-de-campo-verde_29332-1855.jpg"
```

Example of url that doesn't work:

```
"https://veja.abril.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/tecnologia-samsung-s10-01.jpg"
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to look on the img that returns from np.asarray. look on its shape. Does it looks like a color image?

Comment: this line returns a code that doesn't represent the colors. Honestly I dont know what they mean, here is a sample:

[255, 216, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1....]

cv2.imdecode should take each number and convert to a BGR array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is some issue reading the file with `urllib` **but I didn't dig into**.

I tried with `import urllib.request as ur` instead of `from urllib.request import Request, urlopen`.

This works for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as ur
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # for testing in Jupyter

def urlToImage(url):
    resp = ur.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image
```

Test on Jupyter:

```
url = "https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/paisagem-ambiente-bonito-de-campo-verde_29332-1855.jpg"
im = urlToImage(url)
plt.imshow(im[:,:,::-1])
```

Comment: now i'm testing your solution and it almost works. If I pass the url in the `ur.urlopen(url)`  works fine. But the Request is needed to go through the anti scrapping block and if I use `ur.urlopen(req)`, the problem persists

Comment: Now it works, I just change the Request function, removing the `Range': 'bytes=0-{}'.format(5000)}` part. I dont know what happen, but it works now